# How to load a component twice but both with different text in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, performance, vue-component

I made simple vue component that contains a text field and an image next to each other. On my landing page I want to use that component twice but not the same text. I want to make the website as fast as possible so thats why I want to use 1 component block twice so its already loaded (right?). I don't know a smart solution for this and not even sure if this is a smart way to make the website faster. Do you guys have advice and/or know on what way I should pass the text[image: landing page code][image: The component where I want different text on each component]. Im using Vue 3, Vue CLI 5.0

I was thinking maybe pass it with props but I'm not even sure if this is the best and most smart way of making a website more fast by using 1 component multiple times instead of making a component for each 'text-image' field.

Comment: You could use a slot. https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html

Comment: @bassxzero wow thanks man! Did not even know about that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right to think about speed, but the question should also be on the principle of not repeating your code unnecessarily. So, even if creating two components would not influence the speed, it would not be the best option, since there is a way to do the same thing with a single component.

The solution is to use the `slot`.

ChildComponent:

```js
<template>
  <div>
     <slot name="contentText"></slot>
     <img src="your/path"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

ParentComponent

```html
<template>
    <div>
       <ChildComponent>
           <template #contentText>
              <p>Lorem ipsum 1</p>
           </template>
       </ChildComponent>

       <ChildComponent>
           <template #contentText>
              <p>Lorem ipsum 2</p>
           </template>
       </ChildComponent>
    </div>
</template>
```

You could have used `props`, however, you would lose flexibility and lock your component into an ultra-precise pattern, preventing its reuse in multiple cases. Indeed, the main difference between `props` and `slot` is that `props` can only pass data to the child without any control over how it will be rendered. With slots, on the other hand, the parent can determine exactly how the data should be rendered, or even pass another component.

Thus, with the use of `slot` you can make your component more flexible and reusable in the future

Answer (score 0):

*Do you guys have advice and/or know on what way I should pass the text ?* - Basically it depends how you are going to use this component. If you are planning to reuse this component in several places in your application, In that scenario the approach you are following is correct so that you can just pass `text` and `image URL` dynamically in that component and it will work fine.

```
<text-image :heading="headingText" :description="descriptionText" :image="imageURL"></text-image>
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      taxtImageData: [{
        headingText: "Heading A",
        descriptionText: "Description A",
        imageURL: "Image URL A"
      }, {
        headingText: "Heading B",
        descriptionText: "Description B",
        imageURL: "Image URL B"
      }]
    };
  },
})

app.component('text-image', {
  template: `
    <div style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; margin: 5px">
        <h3>{{ heading }}</h3>
      <p>{{ description }}</p>
    <div>`,
  props: {
    heading: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    image: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  }
}) 
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <text-image
      v-for="(data, index) in taxtImageData"
      :key="index"
      :heading="data.headingText"
      :description="data.descriptionText"
      :image="data.imageURL">
  </text-image>
</div>
```